# PHP calling exec on a php file to execute in the background

Tags: php, exec

I want to execute a PHP file with `exec`, to handle a process in the background, where `1234567` is an id I wish to call from a database to get some information about what I am about to process.

```
exec('/var/www/somescript.php 1234567 > /dev/null &');
```

Are there any potential security issues or problems I may run into?

Should I use `escapeshellarg()` on the parameter I am passing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this depends on if this should be called via a web user and if the arguement or executed command is created by the user.

Using escapeshellarg() in my opinion should always be called as you wouldn't use the MYSQL_ function and not escape any of the input due to risk of SQL injection. Using the exec function is a similar issue, you wouldn't use the script without escaping the input. However, escaping the input doesn't necissarily stop people abusing the script.

You do need to make sure validation has been done for any arguments sent over to the script for example you don't want anyone to comment out your script and in the arguement section inject a completely different script to maybe add a user (this shouldn't be allowed to happen given propper permissions).

I would use this as the last resort, if the issue can't be solved any other way rather then using an exec.

Comment: I have multiple places a customer gets sent in real time, one of those is taking 15 - 30 seconds it is not really acceptable amount of time. All the other places the customer is sent we need to be able to pass back information for each, this one however it can be passed as a background process. 
The id would come from the database no user would ever get access to this part.I am struggling to think of alternatives, pthread's is not something I want to install on the server.

Comment: sorry not entirely sure what you mean. So the background process will be used to send back information? if it was a constant flow of information that could be retrieved multiple times have you tried caching the data using memcached/memcache?

Comment: We use several web services for each customer, the one in question we just need to send the data across it does not matter what the outcome is for the live customer.

Comment: can you not implement a web API and xml feed which the web applications can communicate through which can be set as a constant background service?

Comment: The main issue with that is the amount of time to process if there are 20 customers in one minute, adding this to a queue each taking 15 seconds, it would take 5 minutes to complete, which would put me into a situation where the job would never complete and needing some threaded solution.

Comment: hmm, seem pretty heavy on the processing then. I assume you have the one server, so you are unable to share the processing across several servers? and the same response is not going to be sent more then once so caching is out of the option?

Comment: Each request is different so caching is out, really require a process to be kicked off as the customer comes in. I don't really see any other option but to use exec unless I install pthreads which is not complete or build a .NET service

Comment: are you using a windows server?

Comment: No, our PHP environment is apache, but we also have a windows environment too.

Comment: well if you do go down the route of using exec() i would firstly check that the id is an integer and secondly check to see if the integer exists. Other then that i am a little stuck

Comment: Well thanks for your help and suggestions, never used this before and wanted a bit of a sanity check before I went down this road